# Find the top n rows with ties in R using head

Tags: r

Suppose I had the following data frame *t1*:

```
names <- c('Jack', 'Jill', 'Jane', 'John', 'Job', 'Jim', 'Jason')
pylons <- c(10,5,4,4,3,1,1)

t1 <- data.frame(names,pylons)
t1
head(t1, 5)
```

But I wanted the top 5 rows that included ties. In this case, there are two 4s that tie for 3rd place.  When I do the *head(t1, 5)*, I get:

```
1   Jack    10      
2   Jill    5       
3   Jane    4       
4   John    4       
5   Job     3
```

but I'd also like to see Jim included in this example because Jane & John tie for 3rd place.

Is this possible with the head command in R?

Comment: But Jim and Jason tie for fifth place.

Comment: Are you saying you want the top 5 `pylons` numbers? In general I think `head()` is the wrong function for what you want to do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
t1[ t1$pylons %in% head( unique(t1$pylons) ,5), ]
```

Comment: For me `head(unique(...))` returned more than 5 answers? Of course I have also longer list of unique values, as can be seen in my answer.

Comment: I didn’t have computer to test and head’s default is 6 so you’ll need a second 5 arg.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for `unique` function, then this might be a solution. This is the data

```
names <- c('Jack', 'Jill', 'Jane', 'John', 'Job', 'Jim', 'Jason','Bill')
pylons <- c(10,5,4,4,3,1,1,0)

t1 <- data.frame(names,pylons)
> t1
  names pylons
1  Jack     10
2  Jill      5
3  Jane      4
4  John      4
5   Job      3
6   Jim      1
7 Jason      1
8  Bill      0
```

Then we need to know the unique values in descending order

```
> t1_unique = sort(unique(t1[,'pylons']),decreasing=TRUE)
> t1_unique
[1] 10  5  4  3  1  0
```

and find first 5 matches to the unique values

```
> t1[t1[,'pylons'] %in% head(t1_unique,5),]
  names pylons
1  Jack     10
2  Jill      5
3  Jane      4
4  John      4
5   Job      3
6   Jim      1
7 Jason      1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also consider using `dplyr::dense_rank` and `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
t1 %>%
  mutate(grp = dense_rank(pylons)) %>%
  filter(grp <= 5)

  # names pylons grp
# 1  Jack     10   5
# 2  Jill      5   4
# 3  Jane      4   3
# 4  John      4   3
# 5   Job      3   2
# 6   Jim      1   1
# 7 Jason      1   1
```

*Edited* As pointed out in comments

```
t1 %>%
  mutate(grp = dense_rank(desc(pylons))) %>%
  filter(grp <= 5)
```

will give you `1 thru 5` rather than `5 thru 1`

To unselect grp

```
t1 %>%
  mutate(grp = dense_rank(pylons)) %>%
  filter(grp <= 5) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

Comment: The way OP's desired output looks, I think you want `dense_rank(desc(pylons))`. Also, you can skip the `mutate` and `select` in practice and one-line it, `filter(t1, dense_rank(desc(pylons)) <= 5)` (though it is nice to illustrate how it works).